# Cognito completeNewPassword shows Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

We are using Cognito for Authenication purpose in our Vuejs application. We have a feature to force reset password after initial login. Now I got an error `Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` after executing the `Auth.completeNewPassword(user, newPassword);`.

We do not try to update any store after or before executing the `Auth.completeNewPassword(user, newPassword);`. I think It happens from amplify plugin.

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:135:1)
    at store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:889:1)
    at Watcher.run (vue.common.dev.js?4650:4563:1)
    at Watcher.update (vue.common.dev.js?4650:4537:1)
    at Dep.notify (vue.common.dev.js?4650:741:1)
    at CognitoUser.reactiveSetter [as signInUserSession] (vue.common.dev.js?4650:1066:1)
    at CognitoUser.authenticateUserInternal (CognitoUser.js?3c43:474:1)
    at eval (CognitoUser.js?3c43:574:1)
    at eval (Client.js?1610:119:1)
```

Following are library versions used
"aws-amplify": "^3.3.14",
"aws-amplify-vue": "^2.1.4",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-docgen-loader": "^1.5.0",
"vue-i18n": "^8.17.3",
"vue-jest": "^4.0.0-0",
"vue-loader": "^15.9.1",
"vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
"vuetify": "^2.2.27",
"vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3",
"vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1",

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

I want to force reset the password after initial login without any issue.